# Xcode Keeps buffering when opening or creating any project

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

So Xcode always worked fine when I used to just open and create ordinary Projects, created via the Xcode interface. For my studies I'm working on a MR application for IPhone using unity. I was able to build an run the project on Xcode a couple of times. After some point Xcode started buffering endlessly whenever I tried to run the project until I have to force quit Xcode. None of my other SwiftUI projects can be opened anymore due to the endless buffering. Creating a new Project opens the editor but then once the editor is open it also keeps buffering until I have to force quit. I had this issue before building with unity and the only thing that worked was completely uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it again. I would prefer to not do that every single week. Also the crash report I receive is insanely long an doesn't provide any exceptions.

At this point I'm really frustrated with Xcode, since no solution seems to work, and yes I did restart my mac.

The first time this happened I tried a lot of suggestions from posts with similar issues, like deleting the derived data contents in my library on the mac, deleting the workspace files etc. None of the suggestions solved the problem. At this point Xcode doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: There is likely something in your code that is causing this. Some endless loop some major leak.

Comment: its not depending on the project, it happens to every project even the ones that ran before and haven't been touched ever since.

Comment: Check the unity forums if this is truly an Xcode problem it will be wide spread and I’m sure a priority since Apple and Unity seem to be working together. Update everything, make sure you are using the latest versions. You have to find the trigger.